# Unable to read string from ESp8266 acess point

Tags: wifi, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, access-point

I am trying trying to read data from ESP8266 web-server while ESP8266 is providing access point. For this I got this code from internet:-

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#include <WiFiClient.h>

#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

const char *ssid = "test";

const char *password = "password";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void handleRoot() {

server.send(200, "text/html", "<h1>You are connected</h1>");

}

void setup() {

delay(1000);

Serial.begin(115200);

Serial.println();

Serial.print("Configuring access point...");

WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);

IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();

Serial.print("AP IP address: ");

Serial.println(myIP);

server.on("/", handleRoot);

server.begin();

Serial.println("HTTP server started");

}

void loop() {

server.handleClient();

}
```

this code is working fine. As you can see, '/' is fetched using this line:-

```
server.on("/", handleRoot);
```

but my need is a bit different, I want to read a complete message after `'/'`. For this I tried this line:-

WiFiClient client = server.available();

so that I can use this line later on:-

```
 String req = client.readStringUntil('\r');
```

But I am getting this error:-

`'class ESP8266WebServer' has no member named 'available`'

I can't find any other way to fetch my data. Can anyone tell me the exact function to read my message.

Comment: `Serial.println(server.uri());`  maybe it's a prop instead of a message, but it's server.uri for sure

Comment: I am trying to use server.uri(); in loop, but it's not working

Comment: it would be used in handleRoot(), to respond to an incoming request. there's also `server.args()` and `server.arg("param")` to get GET params; might be directly what you need.

Comment: got it , I have to use server.onNotFound(handleNotFound); to catch my message. Thanks a lot bro